# SQL query - Get rows only if value falls within range of "last n records" (record-specific)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, a Countries table and a Weather table.  I would like to retrieve all of the names of countries where it has not rained within the last 15 days.

The weather table has a column called "DayNum", which goes from 1 -> infinity and increases by 1 on each day, it is unique.  This table also has a column called "Rain" which is just a bit boolean value of 0 or 1.

Also, not all Countries were added on the same day, so the max DayNum will be different for each country.

Examples of tables below (data is snipped for readability):

Countries:

```
    ID     Name
     1      USA
     2      Cananda
     3      Brazil
```

Weather

```
    ID    Country_id    DayNum    Rain
     1        1           1         0
     2        1           2         0
     3        1           3         1
```

Here is my current attempt at a query (been working on this for days):

```
    SELECT countries.name, weather.daynum
    FROM countries INNER JOIN weather ON countries.id = weather.country_id
    GROUP BY countries.name
    HAVING weather.daynum > (MAX(weather.day_num) - 15) AND SUM(weather.rain) = 0;
```

I *think* this should work, but I'm having serious performance issues. The actual query I need to write deals with different data (same exact concept) and millions of rows. This query seems to get slower at an exponential rate.

Can anyone offer any advice?

Another idea I had was to somehow limit the JOIN to only grab the top 15 records (whilst ORDERing BY weather.day_num), but I Haven't found a way to do this within a JOIN (if it's even possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not interested in the amount of rain, just whether it exists, so...

```
select * from countries
left join
(
        select weather.country_id 
        from weather 
            inner join 
            (select country_id, MAX(daynum) as maxdaynum from weather group by country_id) maxday
                on weather.country_id = maxday.country_id
                and weather.daynum>maxday.maxdaynum-3
                where rain=1
        ) rainy
on countries.id = rainy.country_id
where country_id is null
```

I presume you've already indexed your tables appropriately

Comment: I need to familiarize myself with declare and BEGIN...END, but I don't think this would work since all of my countries have a different max DayNum (I guess my example was a tad weak in this sense). So I think I'd get bad results if, for example, USA was added 15 days before any other country. I've updated my OP to reflect this.

Comment: I'd only optimised out the max(daynum) as I assumed they'd be the same... I'll edit it back in

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include any information about the indices on your tables, but I'm betting the performance issues you are experiencing are related to the group by on the countries name field. It would certainly explain your performance issues if that column isn't indexed.

Having said that, this is a situation that probably calls for a subquery rather than an inner join. I would be tempted to write the query this way:

```
SELECT countries.id, countries.name 
FROM countries 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT country_id 
    FROM weather 
    GROUP BY country_id 
    HAVING weather.daynum > (MAX(weather.day_num) - 15) AND SUM(weather.rain) = 0 
) AS weather
ON weather.country_id = countries.id;
```

Comment: This gives me the error: ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function.
I think this is caused by using aggregate functions (max, sum) in the WHERE clause and not in a HAVING clause?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use a simple variable to store the min daynum required ? I am not a mySQL developer, but something like that will do the trick I think :

```
SELECT @minDaynum := (MAX(daynum)-15) FROM weather;

SELECT DISTINCT countries.name
FROM weather
INNER JOIN countries ON weather.country_id = countries.id
WHERE
    weather.daynum >= @minDaynum AND
    weather.rain = 1;
```

EDIT >> If just one variable doesn't work for your case, maybe try using a temporary table to speed things up (not sure if performances of temporary tables in mysql are really good though...) :

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE min_daynums (country_id int, country_name, min_daynum int);
INSERT INTO min_daynum 
    SELECT countries.id, countries.name, MAX(weather.daynum)-15 
    FROM weather 
    INNER JOIN countries ON countries.id = weather.country_id
    GROUP BY countries.id, countries.name

SELECT min_daynums.country_name
FROM min_daynums
WHERE
    EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM weather
        WHERE
            weather.country_id = min_daynums.country_id
            and weather.daynum >= min_daynums.min_daynum
            and weather.rain = 1
    )
```

Here I just store the min daynum for each country in a temp table. Hope it helps...

Comment: @podiluska suggested this (and has since edited their post). The issue is that not every country has the same value for MAX(daynum). This would probably work if they did.

Answer (score 0):

> I have two tables, a Countries table and a Weather table. I would like to retrieve all of the names of countries where it has not rained within the last 15 days.

Here you go:

```
SELECT * FROM Country
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM Weather
        WHERE
            Rain = 1
            AND DayNum >= 2
            AND Country_id = Country.ID
    );
```

In plan English: for each country, check if there are any rainy days newer than the given day number. If there are, eliminate the country from the result.

Replace `2` with the day number 15 days ago. Index on `{Country_id, DayNum, Rain}` for decent performance. Unfortunately, MySQL is unlikely to execute this query optimally, but there are only so many countries so nested loops shouldn't be too bad since DBMS should be able to execute the inner query as a single index seek.

Alternatively, consider rewriting it as JOIN, for example:

```
SELECT Country.*
FROM Country LEFT JOIN Weather
    ON Country_id = Country.ID
    AND Rain = 1
    AND DayNum >= 2
GROUP BY Country.ID, Country.Name
HAVING MAX(Rain) IS NULL OR MAX(Rain) = 0;
```

A working SQL Fiddle example is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1783/12).